# Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null in IF statement

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I have the error:

> "Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null"  at attacked (JS.js:172).

However the concerned line is:

```
if (document.getElementById("enem").innerHTML  != null)
```

Which was made especially to solve this problem (last time I had this problem so I added this IF and it's still erroneous.

Comment: share full html code with `enem`  or better make live demo

Comment: Why would you expect an `if` statement checking if `innerHTML` exists to solve the problem of whether the element exists?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the element `enem` does not exist.
You should instead check if the element exists:

```
if (document.getElementById("enem")) {
   // element exists

} else {
   // element does not exist

}
```

and then you can go ahead if the element exists.